# Sending additional parameters with Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Pusher with EmberJS and Ember Data. To avoid the push notifications coming back to the same client, I would like to always send the Pusher socketId with each API call.

I can get the socketId from within my controller's actions, but don't know how to send it back.

e.g.

```
        var socketId = this.pusher.get('socketId');

        var project = this.get("model");
        project.save();
```

The problem is, the socketId will be different for each controller. So I can't do it directly in the adapter.

Something like this would be ideal...

```
        var socketId = this.pusher.get('socketId');

        var project = this.get("model");
        project.ajaxParams = { socketId: socketId };
        project.save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar to this, and I think the best place to do it is in the adapter, so you only have to do it once. I'll give my example using the `RESTAdapter` because it's most common, but it'll likely work with any adapter.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajaxOptions: function(url, type, hash) {
        var options = this._super(url, type, hash);
        options.headers = options.headers || {};
        // I don't know what `pusher` is, but you can always inject it into your adapter
        options.headers.socketId = this.pusher.get('socketId');
        return options;
    }
});
```

Now, every API request will include the `socketId` header.

EDIT: To inject the pusher:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'injectPusherIntoStore',
    after: 'pusherConnected',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        application.inject('adapter', 'pusher', 'pusher:main');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a go! Hopefully it will work. I presume ajaxOptions is run on each request, as the socketId is dynamic.

Comment: Looks like pusher isn't available from within the adapter. How would I go about injecting it from a controller?

Comment: Is `pusher` a singleton by chance? It sounds like something that you would want available globally, so I would inject it where you need it using the container. [This method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_inject) has an example of that.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/jamiebikies/ember-pusher), which creates a connection for each Controller, so they each have their own socketId's I believe - therefore can't be shared.

Comment: Actually, if you look at [the source](https://github.com/jamiebikies/ember-pusher/blob/master/lib/ember-pusher/initializer.js), you'll see that it get's registered under `pusher:main`. So all you have to do is set up an initializer like he did, then call `application.inject('adapter', 'pusher', 'pusher:main')`.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, this is all very new to me. Will give it a go and let you know!

Comment: I added an initializer that should work for you, just in case you have some trouble.

Comment: Awesome! I got it working, the only thing that wasn't quite right was the "initializer" param which should be just "initialize". Thanks for helping me out.