# How to use session authentication in ember.js http requests?

Tags: jquery, http, ember.js, http-headers, session-cookies

I'm developing a web (frontend in ember.js - but I'm a newbie) using session authentication in the backend.

I have a bit poor knowledge about sessions and CSRF so I'm basically asking what should I implement this request

```
this.store.createRecord('entity', {'text': 'blabla'}).save();
```

or what else have to be done, so the request can pass through session authentication in the backend.
So far it just returns error 401, non-authorised access.

Comment: JWT? Oauth? What are you using for authentication?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992802/sending-additional-parameters-with-ember-data) may help you out.

Comment: ^ no thats outdated...you can directly add headers function in emberjs 
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization

Comment: and add "X-CSRFToken" from cookie where this token is stored, thanks CodeJack, this worked, it is right answer!

Comment: ok i will add as an answer then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically you might be required to add headers of session ids in your rest requests of Ember Data. To make sure all ember data rest requests have those headers you can add them in application level like below

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: {
    "API_KEY": "secret key",
    "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
  }
});
```

As you mentioned in comments, in your case you needed to add `X-CSRFToken` in your headers